# Does Magento store EAV data across table types?

Tags: magento, entity-attribute-value

suppose you have a product in Magento with an attribute of `foo`.  The value of foo for one product is "1" while the value of foo for another product is "bar".

Does Magento store the "bar" value in `catalog_product_entity_varchar` and the bar value in `catalog_product_entity_int`?  Or will foo always be implicitly stored in _varchar because it's expected that that value may have (in this case) mixed values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento's EAV system uses extreme normalization.

Attribute values are stored in separate tables divided by data type (datetime, decimal, int, text, varchar) and keyed on various entity id numbers.

Where the attribute is stored is dependent on the backend definition. You find this information in the `eav_attribute` table in the `backend_type` column.

Comment: so, all of that attribute's values will be in one type of data, regardless of whether an individual value might qualify as another value, i.e. decimal or integer.  that actually makes sense.  It's like you've typed a variable in other languages :)

Comment: Yep, the table storage datatype is what's declared for attribute `foo` per the assigned type in `backend_type`.

Answer (score 1):

Magento will store the value according to the attribute's backend type. If the backend type is varchar, all the values will be stored in catalog_product_entity_varchar.